# (local/nodal and global) Efficiency using igraph shortest.paths function

Tags: r, graph-theory, igraph, shortest-path

I am trying to calculate local efficiency of a graph using shortest.paths of igraph package.

The local efficiency of a vertice v, by definition, is the "global efficiency" computed among all direct neighbors of v (Latora & Machiori, 2001).
I came up with the code below for global and local efficiency. However, the latter is including the target vertex in its calculation. And in the paper above they say the target vertex has to be taken out.

```
#Global Efficiency (average inverse shortest paths between all u--v vertices)
eff<-1/(shortest.paths(my.graph))
eff[!is.finite(eff)]<-0
gl.eff<-mean(eff,na.rm=TRUE)    

#Mean local efficiency (global efficiency for each node)
gn<-graph.neighborhood(my.graph,1) #list with subgraphs of directly connected graphs
names(gn)<-colnames(my.corr.matrix)
local.eff<-numeric(length(gn))
for (i in 1:length(gn)){
  gn[[i]]<-gn[[i]] - vertex(V(gn[[i]])[grep(names(gn[i]),V(gn[[i]]))]) #doesn't match
  eff.gn<-1/(shortest.paths(gn[[i]]))
  eff.gn[!is.finite(gleff.gn)]<-0
  eff.gn<-mean(eff.gn,na.rm=TRUE)
  local.eff[i]<-gleff.gn
  mean.local.eff<-mean(local.eff, na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

I am trying to match the list name (each element of the list is a subgraph) with the name of the vertex inside that subgraph. I am trying to use 'grep()', but haven't been able to get it right. Could someone give me a hand on that?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that my title doesn't fully account for what my question really was. So I'm answering it myself since I just got it to work.

```
#Mean local efficiency (global efficiency for each node)
gn<-graph.neighborhood(my.graph,1) #list with subgraphs of directly connected graphs
names(gn)<-V(my.graph)$name
local.eff<-numeric(length(gn))
for (i in 1:length(gn)){
  gn[[i]]<-gn[[i]] - vertex(V(gn[[i]])[match(names(gn[i]),V(gn[[i]])$name)]) #MATCHES
  eff.gn<-1/(shortest.paths(gn[[i]]))
  eff.gn[!is.finite(eff.gn)]<-0
  eff.gn<-mean(eff.gn,na.rm=TRUE)
  local.eff[i]<-eff.gn
}
local.eff[local.eff %in% NaN]<-NA
mean.local.eff<-mean(local.eff, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have already written a function to do this that is many times faster than what you've written. See if the following will suit your needs. For smaller graphs (or if you are using Windows), you will possibly want to replace `simplify2array(mclapply(nodes,` with `sapply(nodes,`, and then of course remove the argument `mc.cores=detectCores()`. However this really helps performance on large graphs.

You can see the code at the following link:

[Local efficiency code](http://pastebin.com/XqkEYtJS)

EDIT: Included some benchmark info (where the function `f` is yours, and `g` is what I pasted above). This was done on a laptop with 4 cores @2.10 GHz (Intel i3-2310m).

```
g.rand <- sample_gnp(100, .1)
V(g.rand)$degree <- degree(g.rand)
compare <- microbenchmark(f(g.rand), g(g.rand), times=1e2)
compare
Unit: milliseconds
      expr      min        lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 f(g.rand) 476.9853 4097.2202 4544.720 4539.911 4895.020 9346.873   100   b
 g(g.rand) 299.2696  329.6629 1319.377 1114.054 2314.304 3003.966   100  a
```

Comment: Hi @Chris, Thanks for sharing this. I will take a look at your code . I haven't been programming for long so being able to do this was already a thing for me. This feedback with fancier solutions improves it even more. thanks!

Comment: I noticed that you use (unweighted) degree in your code. Do you think it will run ok if I just change it to weighted degree with graph.strength?

Comment: If you just remove `weights=NA` then it should choose weighting automatically if the graph is weighted.

Answer (score 1):

In case that someone needs the **local efficiency** in **python**, here is my code for that:

### Python version

```
import numpy as np
from igraph import *
np.seterr(divide='ignore')


def nodal_eff(g):
    """
    This function calculates the nodal efficiency of a weighted graph object.
    Created by: Loukas Serafeim (seralouk), Nov 2017

    Args:
     g: A igraph Graph() object.
    Returns:
     The nodal efficiency of each node of the graph
    """

    sp = g.shortest_paths_dijkstra(weights = g.es["weight"])
    sp = np.asarray(sp)
    temp = 1.0 / sp
    np.fill_diagonal(temp, 0)
    N = temp.shape[0]
    ne = ( 1.0 / (N - 1)) * np.apply_along_axis(sum, 0, temp)

    return ne
```